# Gradually change color to PIN (Mark Location) on the map

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a screen of my app that uses the iOS UIMap Map. On the map there are PINs (Mark Location of Apple's Human Interface) that indicate seismometers, and every 6 seconds the map updates and some of these seismometers vibrate and turn red. I have to give the PINs on the map a fade effect, going from bright red to very light red.

```
if annotation.identifier == "redpin" {
   view.pinTintColor = .red
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2.0 ) {
      view.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 110/255, blue: 110/255, alpha: 1)
   }
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2.0 ) {
      view.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 180/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1)
   }
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2.0 ) {
      view.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
   }
}
```

I used this method, using a timer that changes the color of the PINs that vibrate every 2 seconds, giving this fade effect manually. For the first ones that vibrate on the first update this is fine, but then those that come after keep the last color (white) and not red-red light-white.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want a quick "fade" from red to white? And then remain white?

Comment: No, I want a slowly fade red to white and then return red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2.0)` block does not *wait until it's done*... the next line of code will be executed immediately.

So, in your posted code, you are effectively saying:

```
set the pin to Red
wait 2 seconds
set the pin to Medium Red    
set the pin to Light Red
set the pin to White
```

You could fix this with using:

```
.now()+0.25 // wait 1/4 second
.now()+0.50 // wait 1/2 second
.now()+0.75 // wait 3/4 second
```

so each block would execute 1/4 second after the previous one.

Tint Color cannot be animated, so you cannot use it in a `UIView.animate()` block.

However, red-white-red Pin tint color changes *do* look a little "fadey" so you might be happy with:

```
func animPinColor(_ v: MKPinAnnotationView) -> Void {
    // set pin to white
    v.pinTintColor = .white
    // wait 0.25 seconds ... adjust as desired
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
        // set pin back to red
        v.pinTintColor = .red
    }
}
```

Or, if you want a little more control:

```
func animPinColor(_ v: MKPinAnnotationView) -> Void {

    // verbose, for clarity
    let red       = UIColor(red: 255/255, green:       0, blue:       0, alpha: 1)
    let mediumRed = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 110/255, blue: 110/255, alpha: 1)
    let lightRed  = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 180/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1)
    let white     = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        mediumRed,
        lightRed,
        white,
        lightRed,
        mediumRed,
        red,
    ]

    // 1/2 second color animation ... adjust as desired
    let totalDuration: Double = 0.5
    // each step will take totalDuration divided by total steps
    let relativeDuration = totalDuration / Double(colors.count)
    for i in 0..<colors.count {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) * relativeDuration) {
            v.pinTintColor = colors[i]
        }
    }
    
}
```

You can play with the duration / timing, and could even add more "shades of red" to get an even smoother fade.

---

**Edit**

Based on the code you posted, I'm assuming you have a reference to a `MKPinAnnotationView`?

If so, usage would be:

```
if annotation.identifier == "redpin" {
    //view.pinTintColor = .red
    animPinColor(view)
}
```

Comment: If I want to call the function "animPinColor" in another function...how can I do? What do I pass as an argument?

Comment: @andreaghezzi - see the edit at the bottom of my answer.